# Universal app disable ipad temporarly

Tags: iphone, universal

I have created a universal app but would like to temporarly disable ipad until I have finished developing the ipad version. Reason is I would like to submit my iphone app and later work on the ipad version.

At the moment it automatically calls CaveConditionsAppDelegate_iPad.h/m when starting with ipad...

any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your **build settings** change the **Targeted Device Family** to iPhone only.

Beware that if you've released a version for iPad already, you can't drop support for it later.

**From Comments:**

Solution was to remove the *"Main nib file basename (ipad)"* from the **plist**.

Comment: that didn't work. I had to remove "Main nib file basename (ipad)" from the app.plist. It is the first release so no ipad version yet.

Comment: Ok. I'll add your solution to my answer so anybody with the same problem has two answers to try.

Comment: Did you get pass Apple's review process?